# Playframework 2 with Oracle throws InvocationException

Tags: oracle, hibernate, playframework-2.0, ebean

When running the "java/computer-database" sample with an Oracle db instead of the H2 one, `Computer.find.byId()` results in "com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.".
The `Application.list()` is showing the correct data.

I have this in my application.conf:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xx.xx.xx:1521:somename"
db.default.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

In my lib directory I have
ojdbc6.jar
orai18n.jar

When searching for examples on how to use oracle in playframework 2.0, I noticed that you should have a line similar to this one in application.conf:
jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle11gDialect

However, this (or any other version number I can come up with) gives an error :
PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

I have already placed hibernate-3.3.2.jar in my lib folder, but somehow play is not using it.

Does anybody know how to fix this, so I can use oracle with the play! framework 2.0?

Comment: Are you using the 'Ebean sample' or the 'JPA sample'?

Comment: The ebean version. Is the 'jpa.dialect' property only applicable for the JPA version?

Comment: 'jpa.xxx' properties are indeed only applicable for JPA. You also tagged your question with both Hibernate and Ebean, so you should remove the Hibernate tag. And can you please add the stacktrace?